# Using struct to create a binary tree in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, tree, binary-tree

I would like to create a binary tree with struct in objective-c, below is what i am doing:

```
struct mytree{
    int value;
    struct mytree *parent;
    struct mytree *left;
    struct mytree *right;
};

- (void)insertmytree: (struct mytree *)root value:(int)value{
    struct mytree *temp;
      if (root == nil) {
         temp->value = value;
         temp->left = nil;
         temp->right = nil;
         root = temp;
      return;
      }

      if (value < root->value) {
         return [self insertmytree:root->left value:value];
      }else{
         return [self insertmytree:root->right value:value];
      }
}
```

to generate the tree:

```
struct mytree t1;
t1.value = 10;
t1.parent = nil;
t1.left = nil;
t1.right = nil;

[self insertmytree:&t1 value:8];
[self insertmytree:&t1 value:3];
[self insertmytree:&t1 value:87];
[self insertmytree:&t1 value:45];
[self insertmytree:&t1 value:2];
[self insertmytree:&t1 value:4];
[self insertmytree:&t1 value:9];
```

it doesn't work, please point me in a right direction

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't enough information. Tell us exactly how it fails. Do you get a compilation error? Does your program crash?

Comment: At least one thing thats won't work with this code is that temp is never allocated so everything in the first if statement is always nil.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but this should work.

```
struct mytree{
    int value;
    struct mytree *parent;
    struct mytree *left;
    struct mytree *right;
};

- (void)insertmytree: (struct mytree *)root value:(int)value{
    struct mytree *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct mytree));
      if (root == nil) {
         temp->value = value;
         temp->left = nil;
         temp->right = nil;
         root = temp;
      return;
      }

      if (value < root->value) {
         return [self insertmytree:root->left value:value];
      }else{
         return [self insertmytree:root->right value:value];
      }
}
```

Then you need some mekanism for cleaning up the dynamically allocated memory when you remove items from your tree.

Answer (score 0):

In (Objective-)C(++) you must explicitly allocate any object/structure you dynamically create on the heap, simply declaring a variable of type *pointer to object/structure* does not allocate an object/structure and store its reference in the variable.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

creates a variable, `myArray`, of type *pointer to a mutable array*, `NSMutableArray *`. It does not create an array. The statement:

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

allocates a new mutable array and stores a reference to it in `myArray`.

For heap allocated C structures you need to use `malloc()` which takes as argument the size of the object/structure, which you obtain with `sizeof`.

Do for your example:

```
struct mytree *temp;
```

creates a variable, `temp`, which can hold a reference to a `struct mytree`, and the statement:

```
temp = (struct mytree *)malloc( sizeof(struct mytree) );
```

creates an (uninitialised) `struct mytree` on the heap and stores a reference to it in `temp`.

You also need to free the dynamically allocated memory when you no longer need it. E.g.:

```
free(temp);
```

will free the object/structure referenced by `temp`, which must be an object/structured that was created using `malloc` (or another function from the `malloc` family). Note: This statement does *not* change the value in `temp`, so after this call the value in `temp` is a reference to deallocated memory, if `temp` is staying around you might want to assign `NULL` to it to avoid accidentally accessing deallocated memory.

HTH